# How to detect a notification in android?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I am making some animation in android and I want to pause it whenever notification pops up in screen. For example sms, message from messenger, whatsApp, viber etc.
I don't need to know what is the type of notification or handle it somehow. I just need to know when it pops up so I can call my pause() method. How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a notification listener service.

```
public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {  

    Context context;  

    @Override  
    public void onCreate() {  
        super.onCreate();  
        context = getApplicationContext();  
    }

    @Override  
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

        // Send a braoadcast with some data
        Intent notificationMessage = new Intent("SomeData"); 
        notificationMessage.putExtra("Hello", "World");  

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(notificationMessage); 
    }  

    @Override  
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {  
        Log.i("Msg","Notification Removed");  

    }  
}
```

You can recieve the Local broadcast in you activity as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override  
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
                String data = intent.getStringExtra("Hello");  

                // Do something with the data
            }  
        }, new IntentFilter("SomeData"));  
    }  


}
```

Also register the service in manifest

```
<service  
    android:name=".NotificationService"  
    android:label="@string/app_name"  
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</service>
```

you can find the official documentation here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService

You can also find detailed demo here http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2015/05/android-read-status-bar-notification.html

Comment: Thanks, but in order to use this, user neeeds to allow reading notifications. Is there any other way to know when notification is posted, I don't car what is notification, it content, I just need to be triggered whenever notification is posted. But I would like to do that without forcing user to allow reading notifications.